# Is there any way to get all the _id in mongo which has string values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In one of the collections , we have entry in the collection as 
"_id":"123" and other one as "_id": NumberLong(123)..

Is there any way throgh mongo cli to remove all the entries with _id as string type instead of Long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $type operator to identify various data types

`db.user_data.remove( { _id: {$type : 2}})`

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/